# ASP.net CS1061 Compilation Error on deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm having a bit of a pain here and I just can't figure out what's wrong.

I have an ASP.net project which I deployed on a server. At first everything seemed allright, no Errors whatsoever. However, as a last adition I wanted to add a search function to a fairly large list so I added the following syntax to my mark-up:

```
<td>
    Search Server:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLookup" runat="server" OnClick="btnLookup_Clicked" Text="Search" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblFeedback" runat="server" />
</td>
```

and the following in code behind:

```
protected void btnLookup_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblFeedback.Text = "";
    Session["IsSearch"] = true;
    LoadServerList();
}
```

When I run this locally it works just fine as I expect.
HOWEVER!

When I copy these files to the server I get a compilation error:

**Compiler Error Message**: CS1061: ' ASP.ntservice_ reports_ reports_ serverlist_ manage_ aspx ' does not contain a definition for 'btnLookup_ Clicked' and no extension method 'btnLookup_ Clicked' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.ntservice_ reports_ reports_ serverlist_ manage_ aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

it says there is nothing that handles my Clicked event although it does work when I run it through Visual studio.

any ideas?

EDIT:
What I tried myself is

- renaming button
- deleting and readding the button
- add through designer
- renaming click event
- removing the event from markup allows normal execution ... :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is your project a web site or a web application?  I would guess that it's a web application project and that perhaps you don't have the latest DLL deployed from the bin folder.  Check the versions between your machine and the server to verify that they are the same.

Comment: it was my first time deploying something. I didn't know the site itsefl was also compiled seperately. it works now, I copied the latest website dll to the server :D THX

Answer (score 3):

I think this error is generated when you change an object Name, ex.
Text1 -» txtSerialNo I had the same problem but I could fix it. Here is the solution:
Go to Split Mode, click on the textbox/object, in the code remove the line

```
[**ontextchanged="txtSerialNo_TextChanged"**]
```

From:

```
[<asp:TextBox ID="txtSerialNo" runat="server" 
     ontextchanged="txtSerialNo_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox> //remove this line]
```

To:

```
[<asp:TextBox ID="txtSerialNo" runat="server"</asp:TextBox>]
```

I hope it works for you. Bless you.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced same problem. And I made the event handler method public, problem solved!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you deploy the dll?

Answer (score 1):

Do you set

```
<%@ Page ... Language="C#" CodeBehind="... .aspx.cs" Inherits="..." .../>
```

in your page directive correctly?

Comment: yes, because there is a lot more on that page that works as it should be. it's purely the click event that freaks out. I just checked. When I remove the OnClick from the markup page it works ....

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it if you did everything else right:

Try to make an entirely new click event (using the split view, just to be sure you get the method signature right.)

Then copy your code from your previous clicked event into the newly created event, copy the new event's method name to your original button and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the event handler to some thing OnClick="buttonLookup_Clicked"... and changing the event handler signature to match it.

Answer (score 1):

having the same issue myself, I made the method public so that removed the compiler error, then followed that with including everything within

```
<form runat="server">
 .....  
 <asp:Button id...  OnClick="MethodName"/>
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Make the events your onclick events point to public.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the event is signed-up for programmatically AND also in the markup (via the properties)

Answer (score 1):

go to  ***Build ==> Clean Solution ==>  Run (f5)***

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my ASP.NET Development server then its running again.

Comment: Some further explanation would improve this answer. Were you encountering the exact same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with you, but I fix it by include    `CodeFile="xxxx.aspx.cs"` into my **page directive**, hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the form which affected and go to properties, change the Build Action to Compile. typically this error comes when the Build Action changed to resource.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue occurs when there are two projects in solution, and the second project has reference of first project dll.
When you add new members to the class in first project make sure you build the first project first and then second project will compile successfully